# Azure DataFactory - A database operation failed with "Invalid object name"

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analytics

I have a Data Factory datasets where the connection is working, but when I try to "preview" the table structure I get the following error:

```
Error details

Error code
22301

Details
A database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object name 'dbo.[my_table]'.' Invalid object name 'dbo.[my_table]'., SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,State=1, . Activity ID: 05746029-7365-4d9d-b60a-2cdc06b126ec
```

I've checked, and the table in question exists and is accessible via the connection credentials being used. I don't know why it's giving me this error if that is the case?

Comment: try without square brackets

Comment: I replaced the actual name with a placeholder, I don't use square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Select table name from drop down, instead of edit and typing table name manually. Then try to preview table structure.

If that doesn't solve:

- Ensure that if you have a case sensitive collation on your database
  that the object names in your query match the exact case.
- Check that the default schema for your user hasn't changed on this
  database. Although the default schema is usually [dbo], it can be
  changed.
- If you are using stored procedures or parameters, the parameter name
  of the stored procedure should be the same as the tableName defined
  in the dataset. Please verify it.